# Set active image for UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have defined a `UITabBar` programmatically but how can I set a custom `UITabBar` icon when the item is active?

Here is my code for declaring the `UITabBar` button, but how can I set a custom image when it's active?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Free", @"Free");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Free.png"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the normal and selected states for each tab bar item:

```
UIImage *normalImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Free.png"];
UIImage *selectedImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Free_Selected.png"];

[self.tabBarItem setBackgroundImage:normalImg forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //Normal
[self.tabBarItem setBackgroundImage:selectedImg forState:UIControlStateSelected]; //Selected
```

Comment: hello sir, it gives error, no visible interface for uitabbaritem for selector setbackgroundimage.

Answer (score 8):

New in iOS7, the way to do this now is with the `selectedImage` property on `tabBarItem`:

```
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Free_Selected.png"];
```